# Promise.all won't work in AWS lambda code

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, aws-lambda, promise

I have tested this code locally several times, but after deployment on AWS, it stopped working. I have just added simple code to test Promise.all, but the function doesn't wait at all. What am I doing wrong here?

```
export const myHandler = async (event, context, callback) => {
  console.log(event)

  await getParam().then(
    (resolvedValue) => {
      createBuckets()
    },
    (error) => {
      console.log(get(error, 'code', 'error getting paramstore'))
      return { test: error }
    }
  )

  async function createBuckets() {
    console.log(`inside createbuckets`)

    const timeOut = async (t: number) => {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
          resolve(`Completed in ${t}`)
        }, t)
      })
    }

    await timeOut(1000).then((result) => console.log(result))

    await Promise.all([timeOut(1000), timeOut(2000)])
      .then(() => console.log('all promises passed'))
      .catch(() => console.log('Something went wrong'))
  }
}
```

My createBuckets function was a const and arrow function as well. but for some reason, even that shows as undefined when I deploy it. When I changed it to function createBuckets, it started working.

[image: Logs]

Comment: Try `return createBuckets()`.  When using `.then` a promise needs to be returned for it to be waited on.  In this case `undefined` is returned while the `async` `createBuckets` runs on the next tick of the event loop

Comment: Also it's easier to use `async/await` rather than mixing in the `.then` promise API's.

Answer (score 2):

As Matt already mentioned in the comments, you need to `return createBuckets()` in the `.then` callback for it to work properly.

I also think that mixing `async/await` and `.then/.catch` can be a bit confusing, so it's best to stick with one or the other for the most part.

Here's how I would rewrite your code:

```
const timeOut = (t: number) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve(`Completed in ${t}`)
    }, t)
  })
}

async function createBuckets() {
  console.log(`inside createbuckets`)

  const result = await timeOut(1000);
  console.log(result);

  await Promise.all([timeOut(1000), timeOut(2000)])
  console.log('all promises passed')

  // The Promise from timeOut cannot reject, so there's no point in catching it.
  // If you need to catch the error when you perform some real work, then you can 
  // use try/catch.
}

export const myHandler = async (event, context, callback) => {
  console.log(event)

  try {
    const param = await getParam()
    await createBuckets()
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
    return { test: error }
  }
}
```